# `$prepend` parameter in the Composer Class Loader

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using the loader in Composer like so.

```
/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/dependencies/autoload.php';
$loader->add('MyAppNamespace', __DIR__, true);
```

As you can see the loader takes 3 parameters, which is documented here: https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/1.0.0/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.html#method_add .

I am extremely confused at to what the 3rd boolean parameter `$prepend` does. The link above says the `$prepend` means the following: `Whether to prepend the directories`. However I have no idea what this means.

Can someone please explain what the `$prepend` parameter does with an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [composer code](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L126):

```
$first = $prefix[0];
if (!isset($this->prefixesPsr0[$first][$prefix])) {
    $this->prefixesPsr0[$first][$prefix] = (array) $paths;
    return;
}
if ($prepend) {
    $this->prefixesPsr0[$first][$prefix] = array_merge(
        (array) $paths,
        $this->prefixesPsr0[$first][$prefix]
    );
} else {
    $this->prefixesPsr0[$first][$prefix] = array_merge(
        $this->prefixesPsr0[$first][$prefix],
        (array) $paths
    );
}
```

As you can see, `$prepend` determines if paths provided by you (`__DIR__`) will be prepended or appended. Usually it doesn't matter, as you have only one path per namespace, but you could have more, and e.g. use this mechanism to override some class delivered with vendor lib by your own implementation.